# Free a Unicode struct

Tags: c, string, free

I have a pointer to an wide char array, which I want to free. 
What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Can you post some code please? What do you have so far? How did you obtain the pointer?

Comment: What's the *type* of the struct? How was it allocated? C doesn't care about Unicode.

Comment: The question does not seem to be related to Unicode!

Comment: Call free() just like any other memory

Comment: Using free() solved it, some functions I used gave false output...

Comment: Can you update the question either to explain what you mean by "Unicode struct", or just delete the word "Unicode"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on how the memory was allocated.

If `malloc()` was used, pass the address of the allocated memory to `free()`.  If it came from a third-party library, see that library's documentation.  If the struct is actually a local or global variable, don't worry about cleaning it up at all.